# Port Forwarding Raspberry Pi doesn't work

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I configured my Cisco Router to use Port Forwarding for ssh connection to Raspberry Pi and to apache server. There are some screenshots of router:
[image]

[image]

This is from **ifconfig** of my Raspberry

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:a7:02:f6  
      inet6 addr: fe80::1956:589a:5c63:56db/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:f2:57:a3  
      inet addr:192.168.0.11  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fef2:57a3/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:265 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:280 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:33054 (32.2 KiB)  TX bytes:47380 (46.2 KiB)
```

**My public ip from whatismyip.com**
[image]

**And my attempt to connect :**
    [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Internet address in the Carrier-Grade NAT range: `100.64.0.0/10. This means your ISP is using CGN, and you would need it to forward the port for you, but that is unlikely to happen, since all traffic hitting the NAT point in the ISP network to that port would be sent to you. Normally, residential ISPs have, buried in the fine print of your contract, a prohibition against running servers from your network.

The RIRs have run out of IPv4 addresses to assign to the ISPs, so the ISPs are hoarding public IPv4 addresses for the business which are willing to pay for them. The solution being employed by more and more ISPs is to use CGN for residential users. [RFC 6598, IANA-Reserved IPv4 Prefix for Shared Address Space](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598), defines this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Port Forwarding to Raspberry Pi doesn't work

Your internet ISP address `100.66.x.x` shows that your ISP is using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

On a Carrier Grade NAT Network, Port Forwarding will (usually) not work.

You can use a VPN Service as an alternative to Port Forwarding (see below for details).

> **Carrier-grade NAT usually prevents the ISP customers from using port forwarding**, because the network address translation (NAT) is usually implemented by mapping ports of the NAT devices in the network to other ports in the external interface.
>
> This is done so the router will be able to map the responses to the correct device; **in carrier-grade NAT networks, even though the router at the consumer end might be configured for port forwarding, the "master router" of the ISP, which runs the CGN, will block this port forwarding because the actual port would not be the port configured by the consumer**.

Source [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)

---

#### Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT

> **Common Problems**
>
> There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding.

...

> 2. ISP controlled firewalls don't allow you to receive incoming connections

...

> **Solutions**
>
> For each problem is a recommended solution. Granted, the solutions for problems like this are not always free.

...

> Lastly you may use a proxy or VPN service. This method should always work.
>
> **Using a VPN Service as an Alternative to Port Forwarding**
>
> The first step is to purchase a VPN service such as AirVPN. To use a VPN, you will need to install a VPN Client. You may either use AirVPN's client, or the OpenVPN Client.
>
> The next step is to log in to AirVPN's website, and from there you can tell them which ports you would like forwarded to your computer.
>
> It is important to note that when you connect to a VPN using AirVPN and your VPN client, you will receive a new external IP address.

Source [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm)